# What is the efficient way to write this custom operation in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I want to implement a new operation similar to matrix multiplication in tensorflow. For example, If there are two matrices `input, W` and  `C = Op(input,W)`, then, `C[i,j] = tf.math.reduce_prod(input[i,:] - W[:,j])`. For implementing this operation I am planning to use two "for-loops" iterating over rows & columns, however, I believe that  the for-loop implementation will decrease the training performance. I tried looking into the implementation of `tf.lingalg.matmul()` but the function seems to call C++ binaries which are not editable. Is there any way to speed up this computation? The following is the function I have written to implement Op(input,w):

```
def difference(input,w):
    result = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((input.shape[0],w.shape[1]),dtype=tf.float16))
    for i in tf.range(0,input.shape[0]):
        for j in tf.range(0,w.shape[1]):
            result[i,j].assign(tf.math.reduce_prod(input[i,:] - W[:,j]))
    return result
```

Comment: Can you post your current solution, with inputs and expected outputs? This will make it much easier for SO users to understand your question.

Comment: Updated the question with current solution.